# Размещение и тестирование приложения в Android Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play

При размещении приложения в Android Google Play Console  указываю альфа тестирование, что обозначает открытое тестирование, кому будет доступно приложение ?

указал закрытое ..но там нужно обязательно указывать почтовый адрес.. можно ли сделать  чтобы приложение было доступно по ссылке?

Comment: там все расписано по каждому пункту, внимательно читай справку https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213